# Virtual Machine Scale Sets - Error Installing Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.TeamServicesAgent

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-vm-scale-set

I created virtual machine scale set and i followed the below documentation to configure it as an agent pool in azure devops.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/scale-set-agents?view=azure-devops#troubleshooting-issues

After configuring , i cant find the agents under the agent pool created in Devops.

When i checked the instances in VMSS, the instances are update with latest model and they are up and running.On furthur anlaysis I found that there was an issue installing extension for devops on the instance

Below are the logs from the faulty VM

```
[2024-03-26T12:45:11.409Z] Executing: C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.TeamServicesAgent\1.31.0.0\enable.cmd  
[2024-03-26T12:46:09.198Z] Execution Complete.
######
Execution Output:
[2024-03-26T12:45:14] Sequence Number: 1
[2024-03-26T12:46:08] Error occured during Enable Pipelines Agent Error
[2024-03-26T12:46:08] System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: .agent file not found. The agent was not set up correctly.
```

Execution Error:

```
######
 Number of Tries: 1
Command C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.TeamServicesAgent\1.31.0.0\enable.cmd of Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.TeamServicesAgent has exited with Exit code: -1
```

Comment: Are you using a custom Windows VM image or the default marketplace image? Is there any pipeline agent service that is already installed and captured together within the image? Is there any pipeline agent **on-line** since the creation of the agent pool or never? Have you checked the agent logs in your agent machine under path `C:\agent\_diag` to see if there is useful error that shows why the agent service installation was failed?